# Inserting data scattered from multiple tables into a table

Tags: sql

I'm at beginners level in SQL and I hope that get guidance.

Table 1, 2 and 3 are Tables without a UniqueID.

TABLE1

[image]

TABLE2

[image]

TABLE3

[image]

Then I inserted all records of the 3 tables into Table4 with a uniqueID and source table column.

TABLE4

[image]

My goal is to insert data from Table 4 INTO Table5 but instead of creating an update statement on each NULL records per column. Is there a better way to insert it in one query? I tried using row partition and case function but it doesn't work.

Desired Table5 output.

Edit: For EZRA FITCH STATE = OREGON, it is entered according to the table rank. Rank 1=Table1
Rank 2=Table2
Rank 3=Table3

[image]

Comment: How do you define that the STATE for Ezra Fitch ends up as OR - each source table has a different value. What's the business rule that defines that?  What about the EMPCODE - why would it be those values rather than e.g. 5 or 9 for Fred Perry? What code have you tried - post your attempt too

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Edit: For EZRA FITCH STATE = OREGON, it is entered according to the table rank. Rank 1=Table1 Rank 2=Table2 Rank 3=Table3

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
 INSERT INTO Table4 (FirstName, LastName, State, Position, EmploymentStatus, Source)
        SELECT FirstName, LastName, State, Position, EmploymentStatus, 'Table1' FROM Table1;
        
    INSERT INTO Table4 (FirstName, LastName, State, Position, EmploymentStatus, Source)
        SELECT FirstName, LastName, State, Position, EmploymentStatus, 'Table2' FROM Table2;
        
    INSERT INTO Table4 (FirstName, LastName, State, Position, EmploymentStatus, Source)
        SELECT FirstName, LastName, State, Position, EmploymentStatus, 'Table3' FROM Table3;


 INSERT INTO Table5(FirstName, LastName, State, Position, EmploymentStatus)
  SELECT
    MAX(FirstName),MAX(LastName),MAX(State),MAX(Position),MAX(EmploymentStatus)
FROM table4
group by FirstName , LastName
```

this code work

table5 output:
[image]

Comment: This is gold! Thank you!

Comment: Does Max apply to string value?

Comment: Yes it applies. I tested it myself

Comment: My fault, I forgot to mention that I'm using postgresql. Does max function for string value apply on all RDBMS platforms? LIke SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL and Postgre?

Comment: Go to https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html and test. Yes it works at all RDBMS platforms.